# Parsing nested json in python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to parse the following json to get the Item (Item1, Item2 ...) and URL fields out of the payload.  I'm able to parse out the Item1, Item2 no problem with something like this but I'm at a loss of how to get the URL out of it as well

```
resp = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(resp.text)
items = data["items"]
for item in items:
    print(item)
```

I've tried adding something like this just to get the subscriptions but receive `KeyError: 0`

```
subscriptions = data["items"][0]
```

Payload:

```
{
  "items": {
    "Item1": {
      "subscriptions": [
        {
          "url": "https://someurl.com",
          "name": "Customer1",
          "categories": [
            "Appointment"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "Item2": {
      "subscriptions": [
        {
          "name": "Customer2",
          "url": "https://someotherurl.com",
          "authPass": "",
          "authUser": "",
          "categories": [
            "Appointment"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep digging

```
Item1_url= data["items"]["Item1"]["subscriptions"][0]['url']
```